# Filesystem creation fails when trying to install Ubuntu over Windows

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, windows

I'm completely new to Ubuntu , I want to replace windows (that had been crushed while trying to install Ubuntu) but whenever I choose erase windows to install Ubuntu I get this error:

> The ext4 file system creation in partition #1 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) failed.

Just please I need practical steps to solve this issue

Comment: First, open the disk utility and check the drive's SMART status to see if it is failing.  Then after you get this error, open a terminal and run `dmesg | tail` and edit your question and paste in the output.

Comment: For me it was not using english as a language, restarted and used english instead of Swedish. And the installation went on without issues. :)

Answer (score 6):

This is an answer I wrote for someone else but it will help you for certain so I am copying it here.

Hello
It would be easiest to just start from the beginning so lets do that, okay?

First, boot to your USB  or DVD and let Ubuntu start a live session. You will see an icon on the desktop that says Install Ubuntu on your desktop. Launch (click on) it.

When you get to the screen where it asks you if you want to replace an existing install or install next to it or Something Else, choose Something Else.

Now you will see a screen that will let you see the hard drive you want to install to. Make sure you choose the correct drive you want to install ubuntu on! On that screen you will need to first delete any existing partitions so you can start fresh.

Start at the bottom of the listed partitions and right click on each one and choose Delete. After you have done this to all the partitions, click on Apply.

When you have deleted everything your drive will show as completely unallocated space! Sometimes some partitions cannot be deleted right away so delete all you can at first and click Apply, then start over from the bottom until they are all deleted.

Now you want to create the necessary partitions for you to install Ubuntu.

Create the following partitions:

1. a boot partition `/boot` and give it 250 MB of space, choose `ext4` for the format.
2. a root partition `/root` and give it 15000 MB of space and `ext4` format
3. a swap partition `/swap` and give it 4096 MB of space (it will format to swap)
4. a home partition `/home` and give it the rest of the space and format it to `ext4`.

   Now just finish the install and it will run beautifully.

Comment: Or if your lazy you can just restart once all the partitions are deleted and Ubuntu should then install as normal getting past the error.

Comment: Or, if you're lazier, boot to the live CD. Open the dash and type 'disks'. Open it, and find your internal hard drive. Hit the menu button at the top, and choose 'Format...'. In the dialog, hit 'Format...' to format the drive, then once it's done close Disks. Now open the installer and install as normal.

Comment: I ran into the same problem, but this didnt work. I tried the above and got the same exact issue with the creation of file system failing

Comment: I used gparted to do the same "unallocated space" step, and then normal installation worked (I didn't have to select "something else")

Answer (score 1):

For me,was using RAID Controller From BIOS, To erase Disk By Removing it from Array and Back it as I want. 
(you will erase your Disk)

Answer (score 0):

I figured I'd chime in because I've been reading these forum posts for days now. I realize my case was VERY rare but figured I'd post how I solved it.

I couldn't get Ubuntu 16.04 or Ubuntu 18.04 to create a partition through installation, gpart or fdisk. I played with the bios many times swapping between legacy and EFI changing the error to `The efi file system creation in partition #1 of ... failed`. I even swapped hard-drives, both of which were new. I tried the above solution to no avail.

As a last resort I changed which port my the drive was plugged into on the mother-board. I realize this isn't most peoples issue, but it was mine. It was difficult to fix as the system detected the drive, it just made it write-protected on that port.

Answer (score 0):

When the partitioning screen comes up, it asks me if I want to unmount the partitions, or continue as is. Choose "unmount the partitions". Then, on the next screen, delete each existing partition, and recreate them from scratch. Worked for me after that. I was installing the "server" image btw.

Answer (score 0):

Change the boot mode in BIOS from Legacy to UEFI.

During the installation process, delete the existing partitions first, and then select "using the entire disk" for partition.