# The efi file system creation in partition #1 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) failed

Tags: partitioning, software-installation, uefi

I have been trying to install linux on my laptop and I keep getting this error. I select the automatic install for ubuntu and every time it goes to install this happens, this also happens when I attempt to install SteamOS which is built of Debian. I've been searching for hours now and while I've seen many people reporting issues like this, no one seems to have a solution.

Comment: Possibly related to / duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/356522/filesystem-creation-fails-when-trying-to-install-ubuntu-over-windows Please take a look at the first answer on that question -- the key seems to be choosing manual (not automatic) partitioning, then deleting all existing partitions, then setting them up manually in the Ubuntu installer

Comment: I tried that, and I tried it again just now, that doesn't work. I just get the same error, but it says ext4 instead of efi